# Windows 10 KB4499167 won't update

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm trying to install KB4499167 on Windows 10 Professional.

After updating, when the computer restarts, at the light blue screen, the last message is something like "Unable to update, rolling back" (sorry, my Windows speaks hungarian...)

I get a message after installation, that the installation of KB4499167 wasn't successfull, error code: 0x800f0922.

I've downloaded the full KB4499167 package, so it can't be network error, and I have 290 GB free in the Windows' drive.

In the Event manager there are messages about "The installation of KB4499167 was successfull, restarting", and then the next message "Unable to set KB4499167 package state to installed."

I've tried all ideas of these two solutions:

- [Install update Error 0x800f0922](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/install-update-error-0x800f0922/87a78355-1a84-4e0f-a0be-28f99a075e50)
- [failed install attempt error code 0x800f0922](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/failed-install-attempt-error-code-0x800f0922/c5eb31d7-f04f-4ff8-9d6f-f39e4f03944b)

How can I perform the update?

Comment: Try to install it in Safe mode. Is `.Net framework` the latest version? Check also if you need to [expand the System reserved partition](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/we-couldnt-update-system-reserved-partition).

Comment: `KB4499167` was released last month.  Is there a reason you have not installed a cumulative patch in a month?  `KB4503286` is the current cumulative patch.  Are you able to install that?

Answer (score 0):

If your partition style is **GPT** then please consider the following:

The error code 0x800f0922 is mainly due to your *System Reserved Partition* being full or insufficient in size. While Windows recommends the **max size** to be 500 MB, it is **HIGHLY ADVISED not to tamper with the size as it could lead to serious bootup issues in case you mess up.**

Here's what I did [Steps 1-4] and how I would proceed if it was not working [Step 5-11]:

1. Run Disk Clean-up and safely delete delivery optimization and thumbnails files [I liberated almost 1 GB with this].
2. Run services.msc and make App Readiness service Automatic and restart the service.[Optionally you can follow the same steps for Background Intelligent Transfer Service and Windows Update Service]
3. Temporarily Disable your Domain, Public and Private network Firewall Settings.[Remember to re-enable them later]
4. Restart your system to see if it works.
5. If Step 4 is not working, then try repairing the rebuilt performance counter setting via `https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-0x800f0922-installing-windows-update-windows-10/#:~:text=The%20Windows%20Update%20error%200x800F0922,is%20less%20than%2015%20MB.` [You may need to run the commands TWICE to fix any command-line errors]. Restart your system to see if it works.
6. If Step 5 is not working, then try net stop wuauserv,  net stop bits, net stop dosvc followed by net start wuauserv,  net start bits, net start dosvc RESPECTIVELY, on your CMD in Administrator mode. Restart your system to see if it works.

> > **BACKUP YOUR FILES NOW SINCE THE NEXT STEPS CAN BE POTENTIALLY HAZARDOUS FOR YOUR SYSTEM.**

7. If Step 6 is not working, then try temporarily disable secure boot on your BIOS settings. Restart your system to see if it works. [Remember to re-enable secure boot once your issue is solved]
8. If Step 7 not working, try using cmd commands DISM (scanhealth,checkhealth restorehealth) and scf/scannow. Wait for them to complete. Restart your system to see if it works.
9. If Step 8 is not working, try manually downloading the faulty update from Windows Update Catalog and install them. Restart your system to see if it works.
10. If Step 9 is not working, try resizing the System Reserved Partition [**PROCEED WITH EXTREME CARE**] using either CMD via `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows-10-46865f3f-37bb-4c51-c69f-07271b6672ac` or making use of Windows partition tools like EaseUS, MiniTool, Gparted, and AOMEI among others.
11. If Step 10 is not working, then please seek professional help.